# Ruby on Rails function for this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have a function which get **start_day** and **end_day** as two string type parameter and returns the list of dates inside the specified date span including start and end days, anyone can provide a efficient code block?

```
def get_list_of_dates(start_date, end_date)
  ...
  return dates
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def get_list_of_dates(start_date, end_date)
  (Date.parse(start_date)..Date.parse(end_date)).to_a
end
```

If `Date.parse` doesn't accept the string (it doesn't accept many formats), you may want to check out [chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have ActiveSupport try:

```
start_date = Date.parse(start_date)
end_date = Date.parse(end_date)
for date in start_date..end_date
  puts date
end
```

That should give you:

```
...
Sat, 05 Mar 2011
Sun, 06 Mar 2011
Mon, 07 Mar 2011
Tue, 08 Mar 2011
Wed, 09 Mar 2011
...
```

With ActiveSupport you can do things like:

```
# if you exclude to_date you get all Times in between
for date in 17.days.ago.to_date..Date.yesterday
  puts date
end
```